# RadioButtonList inside DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a radiobuttonlist control inside a datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlfilteritem" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
    RepeatColumns="3">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblfilteritem" runat="server">
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

How can i catch the control of radiobutton in an event using findcontrol?

Comment: on which event you want to get this control ???/

Comment: i have a dropdownlist and i need to get radiobutton control in dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event

Comment: where is the dropdown inside the datalist or outside???

Comment: @ranjenanil: Edited my answer accordingly. Remember to provide such important informations next time in the first place ;)

Comment: see tim's answer it will solve your prob..

Comment: if our answers solved your problem then please accept it.........

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property to get your `DataListItem`. Then you can use `FindControl` to get the reference to your `RadioButtonList`.

For instance, assuming there's another control in the `DataList` that posts back like a `DropDownList`. If you want to find the `RadioButtonList` from within the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList) sender;
    DataListItem dli = (DataListItem) ddl.NamingContainer;
    RadioButtonList rblfilteritem = (RadioButtonList)dli.FindControl("rblfilteritem");
}
```

If the `DropDownList` instead is outside the `DataList` you could enumerate all `DataListItems` via [`Items` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.items.aspx):

```
foreach(DataListItem dli in DataList1.Items)
{
     RadioButtonList rblfilteritem = (RadioButtonList)dli.FindControl("rblfilteritem");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have dropdownlist outside the datalist then you will have array of all values of radiobuttonlist's so for that try the following code

```
foreach(DataListItem data in dtdatalist1.Items)
{
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)data.FindControl("rbl");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void dlfilteritem_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e) {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {            
            RadioButtonList RBL = ((RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("PopularCity"));
            RBL.DataSource = dataTable; 
            RBL.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you find your radiobuttonlist find in ItemDataBound function